# What is the difference between 指摘される and 突っ込まれる?

Tags: business-japanese

I always get this two whenever I make a mistake. I think that more or less they are similar but kind of have the feeling that 突っ込まれる has a bit stronger meaning than 指摘される, is this correct?

For example,

```
 He pointed out my mistakes (rough translation, I'd think)

 彼に指摘された。
 彼に突っ込まれた。
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right that they have similar meanings, but I think the connotations are different.

指摘 is very neutral; you are simply pointing out a fact, not making a value judgement.

突っ込む, on the other hand, has more of a connotation of pouncing on a weakness, especially one the other person was hoping would pass unnoticed.  So you can point out a flaw in someone's story, a grammatical mistake--or, relatedly, a joke that the other person made with a straight face!

Comment: I think this captures it best. 突っ込む has that "verbal jab" flavor to it, and it's often done to get a laugh at the expense of pointing out a flaw or misstep.

Answer (score 1):

指摘される looks more formal usage to me, like you got 指摘された by your manager, but 突っ込まれる is more frank, like your college に突っ込まれる because you did something not correct.